# C++ Overload Static Function with Non-Static Function

Tags: c++, static, overloading, non-static

I would like to print two different things depending on whether a function is called statically with `Foo::print()` or from an instance of `Foo foo; foo.print();`

EDIT: Here is a class definition that definitely does not work, as answered by a few people already.

```
class Foo {
    string bla;
    Foo() { bla = "nonstatic"; }

    void print() { cout << bla << endl; }
    static void print() { cout << "static" << endl; }
};
```

However, is there a good way of achieving this effect? Basically, I would like to do:

```
if(this is a static call)
    do one thing
else
    do another thing
```

Phrased in another way, I know PHP can check if the `*this` variable is defined or not to determine whether the function is called statically. Does C++ have the same capability?

Comment: both versions of `print()` bear the same signature. And I don't think they can be overloaded this way.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

No, it is directly prohibited by the standard:

> **ISO 14882:2003 C++ Standard 13.1/2 – Overloadable declarations**
>
> Certain function declarations cannot
>   be overloaded:
>
> - Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded.
> - Member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter types cannot be overloaded
>     if any of them is a `static` member function declaration (9.4).
>
> ...
>
> *[Example:*

```
class X {
    static void f();
    void f();                // ill-formed
    void f() const;          // ill-formed
    void f() const volatile; // ill-formed
    void g();
    void g() const;          // OK: no static g
    void g() const volatile; // OK: no static g
};
```

> *—end example]*
>
> ...

Besides, it would be ambiguous anyway since it's possible to call static functions on instances:

> **ISO 14882:2003 C++ Standard 9.4/2 – Static members**
>
> A static member `s` of class `X` may be
>   referred to using the *qualified-id*
>   expression `X::s`; it is not necessary
>   to use the class member access syntax
>   (5.2.5) to refer to a `static member`. A
>   `static` member may be referred to using
>   the class member access syntax, in
>   which case the `object-expression` is
>   evaluated. *[Example:*

```
class process {
public:
        static void reschedule();
}
process& g();
void f()
{
        process::reschedule(); // OK: no object necessary
        g().reschedule();      // g() is called
}
```

> *—end example]*
>
> ...

So there would be ambiguity with what you have:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    string bla;
    Foo() { bla = "nonstatic"; }
    void print() { cout << bla << endl; }
    static void print() { cout << "static" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    // Call the static or non-static member function?
    // C++ standard 9.4/2 says that static member
    // functions are callable via this syntax. But
    // since there's also a non-static function named
    // "print()", it is ambiguous.
    f.print();
}
```

---

To address your question about whether you can check what instance a member function is being called on, there is the `this` keyword. The `this` keyword points to the object for which function was invoked. However, the `this` keyword will always point to an object i.e. it will never be `NULL`. Therefore it's not possible to check if a function is being called statically or not à la PHP.

> **ISO 14882:2003 C++ Standard 9.3.2/1 – The this pointer**
>
> In the body of a nonstatic (9.3)
>   member function, the keyword `this` is a
>   non-lvalue expression whose value is
>   the address of the object for which
>   the function is called.

Comment: Thank you for that very clear answer, but I was asking (poorly, I apologize for that) whether the behavior of a static function could be determined based on whether it's called statically or from an instance of the class. See the later part of my question.

Comment: @Lex Fridman: I didn't think you asked poorly. You asked "Does C++ have the same capability?" and I answered that you can't based on the C++ standard (which *defines* the language).

Comment: I'm feeling worse and worse about my phrasing of the question, especially the title. There are actually two questions. First, is if you can overload static with non-static. THAT's what you answered very well. The second question is if you can determine whether there's an instance of the class associated with the call of the static function. As you said, you can use a static function like this: `Foo foo; foo.print();` Can i access the `foo` instance from within that call to `print();` ?

Comment: @Lex Fridman: Ah, okay. You have clarified it for me, so don't worry about your phrasing. I'll answer that part.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not allowed. I don't see any clean way of achieving this. What is exactly the problem that you want to solve this way?

Comment: It's a little complicated to explain but I have some non-static variables that I would like the static function to access when it is called from an instance of the class. I could just name the function something else and make it non-static, but I thought it would provide a nice consistent API that just has one function available to the user. Sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lex - you seem to be misunderstanding what 'static' means. You *can't* access non-static variables with a static method; you're not dealing with an instantiation of the class. The only way to do that would be to pass an instantiation of the class to the static method.

Comment: I know Brian, but you can call static members "non-statically", so instead of `Foo::print();`, use `Foo foo; foo.print();`

Comment: You're not calling it "non statically" ... that's still calling the same static function in the class, and has nothing to do with the instance of the class you happen to have there. It's no different than `Foo::print();` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325555/c-static-member-method-call-on-class-instance - I believe this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: Ah okay, so the instance of `foo` in that case has no meaning and cannot be accessed from within `print()`. Thanks for that clarification Brian

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, because you can't overload based on a return type.

You can certainly have static methods in a class, but you can't have:

```
static void foo();
void foo();
```

Because they have the same method signature.

**EDIT:** I saw your comment saying why you wanted to do this, and that you wanted to access member variables. You'd need to do this:

```
static void print(Foo f);
void print();
....
static void Foo::print(Foo f)
{
    int a = f.a;
    // do something with a
}
```

(Or create getters and setters in Foo, etc, but that's the general idea)

Comment: But if he does that, the next maintainer will have a big WTF moment, when trying to understand why anyone prefers `Foo::print(f)` over `f.print()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that exactly, see [In silico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365689/c-overload-static-function-with-non-static-function/5365714#5365714).

But you can make `Foo::print()` and `Foo foo; print(foo);` do different things.  (Define `void print(Foo& foo)` in the same namespace as `class Foo`, it will be found by ADL).

In any case, this is not a good idea.  You have two functions very similar in name which do completely different things, which violates good design principles.

Comment: I know it seems like bad design, because I'm not explaining precisely the problem I'm trying to solve. It actually makes sense for what I'm doing. However, in the context of C++ it may be a bad way of doing it. I know it's a good thing to do in an interpreted language like PHP.

Comment: @Lex: The two functions have to be doing different things, so surely one of them can have a different name.  Maybe `Foo::PrintLiveFooCount();` and `Foo foo; foo.print();`?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In case of different return type of functions overloading is not possible in method overloading.

**2)** also if we pass same parameters in the functions define under the same class then it can not be overload.