# Ambiguous call to overloaded static function

Tags: c++

I'm confused by this situation and googling didn't give me the answer. Basically I have the following simple code that doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int a(int c = 0) { return 1; }
    static int a() { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::a() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In compiling this, GCC 4.2 says the call to `A::a()` in `main()` is ambiguous with both versions of `a()` valid candidates. Apple's LLVM compiler 3.0 compiles with no error.

Why is gcc confused about which function I want to call? I thought it was obvious that by qualifying `a()` with `A::` I'm asking for the `static` version of the function. Naturally this code still doesn't compile if I remove the `static` function `a()`, because `A::a()` is not valid syntax for calling the non-`static` `a()`.

Thanks for any comment!

Comment: BTW, quick google search by me: "Name resolution of static and non-static member functions C++" came up with another SO question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365689/c-overload-static-function-with-non-static-function

Comment: oops my google-fu failed me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is because C++ specifies that this is ambiguous. Overload resolution specifies that for `A::a`, since `this` is not in scope, the argument list in that call is augmented by a *contrived A object argument*, instead of `*this`. Overload resolution does not exclude non-static member functions, but instead

> If the argument list is augmented by a contrived object and overload resolution selects one of the non-static member functions of T, the call is ill-formed.

This has recently been subject of extensive discussion both in the committee in context of [core issue 1005](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1005). See [core issue 364](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#364) which considered changing this rule but didn't do so.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. However I'm still struggling to understand, why "overload resolution selects one of the non-static member functions of T". If I understand what you said right, the non-static a() has two arguments: this, and argument with default value (c = 0). The static a() has a "contrived A object argument". Because I'm not supplying a "this" pointer in the call, why would the non-static version be selected?

Comment: No, `this` is not an argument in this call because there is no `this` in scope. That's the reason we pass a "contrived A object argument" in our call. Both of those functions have a implicit object parameter (for static functions that parameter is used only to receive the contrived A object argument). The non-static `a`'s implicit object parameter has type `A&` in your case (`A const&` in const member fncs). The contrived object argument in call `A::a()` matches both implicit object parameters, so you have an ambiguity.

Comment: So this "contrived A object argument" is the same type as *this?

Comment: @fang see in the spec at 13.3.1.1.1p3 and 13.3.1

Answer (score 3):

The reason is name resolution happens before anything else the compiler does, like figuring out which overloaded function to use.

Qualifying the function with `A::` simply tells the compiler to "look inside of `A` to find the name `a`". It doesn't actually help resolve which function you are referring to.

**EDIT**

And so when you type `A::a()`, first the compiler thinks "look in `A` for a member function or member who can use `operator()`".

Then the compiler thinks, "Ok, two possibilities here, which one is being referred to? `a()` or `a(int c = 0)` with a default `c=0`. Not sure.

If you removed the static keyword and called the functions like `obj.a()`, there would still be an ambiguity.

**WRT LLVM's parser**

I would say that it does some extra work for you, which is not required by the standard, which would be to assume `A::a()` is static.

Comment: Can someone answer me, does that mean for `static` functions, the `static` definition forms part of the name mangling, for resolution purposes?

Comment: I don't know.  But name-mangling is a linker problem, not a compiler problem.

Comment: Any insight on why Apple's LLVM compiles it fine? Does that mean LLVM's parser does name resolution in some other order?

Comment: @fang What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Bingo i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 is the one that complains about ambiguity. I tried g++-mp-4.7 and it's the same error.

Comment: @fang see my edit. The compiler can't see from the parameters which one, because you could mean the case of default `int c = 0`.

Comment: Yes I see your point. I guess that must be the reason. However I'm still unhappy with gcc on this because LLVM compiler was somehow able to understand what I want to do. After writing tons of code in Xcode and suddenly decide to try a build with gcc, it's frustrating to see compile errors like this, especially when I've been carefully trying to avoid tricky designs that might be compiler specific.

Comment: @fang no problems :) I understand your frustration too. These things can be hard to debug, and I can see why you want this feature!