# C++ - Initializing a Member variable inside a member function?

Tags: c++

This seems like bad coding practice, but it was the guidelines given to me. I want to preface by saying I have no idea how this will actually be implemented in the main, Im just writing the class.

```
class Example
{
  private:
     static int total;
  public:
    void initalizeTotal();
}

Example::initalizeTotal()
{
   total = 0;
}
```

total will (I guess) be used to count the number of objects of that class.
This is basically what I'm getting at. The problem is how I figure out how to actually call the function. 
I can't just call it in the constructor, sense that would reset total each time. 
And I've tried and failed "check" if the variable has a value yet and if not, call the function.

Is there any advice anyone can give?

EDIT: 
I forgot to include that total is static. And that i MUST have a function that initializes total. Thats a requirement of the assignment.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1b5y48f(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Since `total` should be the same variable for every object, you should make it `static`:

```
class Example {
    private:
        static int total;
}
```

To initialize a static variable, you can place this line in a .cpp file:

```
int Example::total = 0;
```

You do not need to call any function to do this initialization.

Comment: I know this. This is normally how I initialize variables. This is however an assignment where I MUST use a function. Sucks I know -_-

Comment: Must it be a member function? Are you allowed to declare the function as static?

Answer (score 2):

You can make `total` variable static:

```
class Example
{
  private:
     void addObject();
  public:
     static int total;
     Example();
}

Example::Example()
{
   addObject();
}

void Example::addObject()
{
   total++;
}
```

So that it will not belong to any specific object. If you then increase it's value in `addObject()` method which will be called in a constructor, you will get objects count.

To access it, you will not be using any `Example` object, but instead you may use it like this:

```
std::cout << "Objects count:" << Example::total;
```

If you want to initialize it, you do it same way somewhere in your code:

```
Example::total = 0;
```

Comment: The name should change as well, it's not initializing anything.

Comment: You're missing a return type on your definition of `initalizeTotal()` now. Since it doesn't touch the state of any instance it should be `static` also. You'd be better off making it private too otherwise everyone and anyone can mess with what seems to be internal state.

Comment: Also, and I realize this is going beyond the scope of the question, this will break if these objects are ever created simultaneously by multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `'total'` field as `static` variable in order to share with all created objects of type `Example`. And any time instantating a new object increase the `total` field.
Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Example {
   static int total;

   public:
     Example() { total++; }
     static int getTotal() { return total; }
};

int Example::total = 0;

int main() {
    Example a, b, c, d;

    std::cout << Example::getTotal(); // 4
}
```

Comment: Why is `getTotal()` not `static`?

Comment: It should be because it accesses no non-static state and has no need of such access, for the same reason that non-mutating members should be `const`. You [can still call `a.getTotal()` even if it's static](http://stackoverflow.com/a/325572/168175) though, just like calling a `const` member on a non-const instance.