# What's difference in connect a QSqlDatabase?

Tags: c++, qt, qsqldatabase

Many tutorials of QSqlDatabase start a database like this:

```
QSqlDatabase cn = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE",QString::number(id));
```

Would it be different from this:

```
QSqlDatabase cn;
cn.addDatabase("QSQLITE",QString::number(id));
```

or this:

```
QSqlDatabase cn;
cn = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE",QString::number(id));
```

Answer (score 1):

`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase` adds a database to the list of database connections and returns `QSqlDatabase` so

```
QSqlDatabase cn;
cn.addDatabase("QSQLITE",QString::number(id));
```

is wrong and it will not work. Of course next is correct

```
QSqlDatabase cn;
cn = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE",QString::number(id));
```

It is equivalent to

```
QSqlDatabase cn = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE",QString::number(id));
```

As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325555/c-static-member-method-call-on-class-instance) you can call `addDatabase` on class instance. For example next code works too (but I don't think that we should use this):

```
QSqlDatabase sdb,plus;
plus = sdb.addDatabase("QSQLITE");
plus.setDatabaseName("G:/Database/test.db");

if (!plus.open())
{
       qDebug() << "not open";
}
```

Comment: Then is it possible to avoid the "=" operator? I want to do so because I have another problem as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673955/is-this-the-safe-way-to-use-qsql-data-base-in-qt

Comment: @NyarukoUnfortunately I can't help you with this question, if you will not use `=` then you will not be able to do `db.open()`, and in this case your database will not be opened, if you will use `cn.addDatabase` , you will get something like: `QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database`