# System::DateTime returns value of 1/1/1 00:00:00

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, coledatetime

```
COleDateTime m_dt;
m_ctrlDateTime.GetTime(m_dt);
double d = dt.m_dt;
System::DateTime datum; 
datum.FromOADate(d);
```

I am trying to get date and time from a DateTimePicker control and to later on set the value of datum to that value. Datum is System::DateTime (C#). But datum is this "1/1/1 00:00:00" What's the problem?

Comment: Need something like : DateTime now = m_ctrlDateTime.GetTime(m_dt);

Comment: @jdweng How would that work? The `GetTime` member function doesn't return a `DateTime` value. It actually returns a `BOOL`, which means it might even compile, performing an implicit conversion in order to call the `DateTime` constructor that takes a `long`.

Comment: Why do you need the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the very last line:

```
datum.FromOADate(d);
```

[`DateTime::FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) is actually a static member function that *returns* a `DateTime` object. In C++ terms, you can think of it like a [named constructor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Constructor).

It does *not* initialize `datum` like a normal member function would. What's confusing you is the fact that [C++ allows you to call static members using an instance of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325572/366904). In C#, that would not be possible, and you would have gotten a compile-time error alerting you to the problem.

Write the code like this, and you will be fine:

```
COleDateTime m_dt;
m_ctrlDateTime.GetTime(m_dt);
double d = dt.m_dt;
System::DateTime datum = System::DateTime::FromOADate(d);
```

You could also do the following (but it would be similarly confusing):

```
COleDateTime m_dt;
m_ctrlDateTime.GetTime(m_dt);
double d = dt.m_dt;
System::DateTime datum; 
datum = datum.FromOADate(d);
```