# Recursive variable declaration

Tags: c++11, variables, recursion, folly

I have just seen this black magic in [folly/ManualExecutor.h](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/futures/ManualExecutor.h#L141)

```
TimePoint now_ = now_.min();
```

After I grep'ed the whole library source code, I haven't seen a definition of the variable `now_` anywhere else than here. What's happening here? Is this effectively some sort recursive variable declaration?

Comment: I think this question could be improved, if you provided a link to documentation of `TimePoint` (if available in the web), or added declaration of `TimePoint::min()` (copy-paste the relevant lines from .h file, which you must have if it compiles).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325555/c-static-member-method-call-on-class-instance

Comment: yet another way to obfuscate code....

Comment: Looks a bit like `Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();` in java...

Comment: @MDXF: It is.... but avoiding repeating the typename, which might be quite long if it needs template arguments or is qualified.

Comment: A search for TimePoint would have done you more good.

Comment: FWIW, I happened across this stackoverflow question and patched this to be less needlessly opaque: https://github.com/facebook/folly/commit/b727acf4391c4f3300ab0348bf1032a02999b408#diff-30beff23525b19a3404dbfc49d84d25f

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That code is most likely equal to this:

```
TimePoint now_ = TimePoint::min();
```

That means, `min()` is a static method, and calling it using an instance is same as calling it like this, the instance is used just for determining the type. No black magic involved, that's just two syntaxes for doing the same thing.

As to why the code in question compiles: `now_` is already declared by the left side of the line, so when it's used for initialization on the right side, compiler already knows its type and is able to call the static method. Trying to call non-static method should give an error (see comment of @BenVoigt below).

As demonstrated by the fact that you had to write this question, the syntax in the question is not the most clear. It may be tempting if type name long, and is perhaps justifiable in member variable declarations with initializer (which the question code is). In code inside functions, `auto` is better way to reduce repetition.

Comment: From the compiler's perspective, the two ways of writing this are equivalent. In a code review, only one of them would be acceptable. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to guess which one.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, everyone knows your hatred of the four dots of evil.  Be reasonable Cody: sometimes `::` is the best choice!

Comment: Analysis of non-static case -- value computation of the initializer is ordered before the copy constructor call (this syntax is copy-initialization), therefore the constructor has not begun execution, therefore the object's lifetime has not started. Section 3.8 of the Standard says that "Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated, ny glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited
ways. The program has undeﬁned behavior if: the glvalue is used to call a non-static member function of the object."

Comment: The code quoted by the OP is actually a non-static data member, where `auto` is not available.

Comment: @T.C. Hmm. Can you explain more? Looks like method *static constexpr time_point min();* to me, based on Mikel F's answer.

Comment: @hyde `min` is static. The problem is that `now_` is actually a non-static data member of some class, and `now_.min()` is actually its default member initializer.

Comment: @T.C. Ah! I guess that might warrant editing the question a bit to give right context without clicking the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Digging into the code shows that TimePoint is an alias for chrono::steady_clock::time_point, where min() is indeed a static method that returns the minimum allowable duration:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/min